# Send connect.sid through graphql and set it manually

Tags: express, session, cookies, graphql

I am trying to use session/cookies to manage auth on a GraphQL API, (not using JWT's).

I am looking to send the value of expresses `connect.sid` through GraphQL through a `login` mutation, then on the client side, set the cookie manually that way the user session can be established through multiple pages.

I can see that every time any mutation is called it's a different `req.sessionID`.

What I believe I need to do is return the cookie value from the API, set it on the response, then ensure it's being sent on subsequent calls to the GraphQL API.

How do I get the full signed value of the express `connect.sid`?